# Which element of network refused connection

Tags: linux, tcp, udp

How could I determine, which element of the network actually refused/closed the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the network data with Wireshark or tcpdump -- usually the machine that refuses it will generate an error response that it did so. Of course, if it just drops the packet, it won't be refused.